# In Django, how to use a manager as default but not for related fields?

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say I've got `FooManager()` that I set as the default manager for a model `Foo`, i.e. by having it be the first manager that Django encounters in the model definition. Now, admin, dumpdata, and Django generally uses this manager by default, as desired.

However, I don't want related field managers to use `FooManager()`, i.e. if `Foo` has a foreign key to `Bar`, then the related manager `bar_instance.foo_set` should use the "plain" Foo manager (to use the term in Django docs), not `FooManager`.

This doesn't seem possible, because the way to have `FooManager` NOT applied to related fields, is by setting its `use_for_related_fields` attribute to `False`. But all that does is get Django to use the the default manager (as opposed to the "plain" manager) for related fields.

And what's the default manager in this case? `FooManager`! Conundrum.

Any way to make this work, i.e. use `FooManager` as default manager but not for related fields?

NOTE: I'm using Django 1.6. I don't see anything in the 1.7 docs to suggest default/related manager behavior has changed. Also note I do NOT want to have to explicitly set the related manager per the new 1.7 functionality [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#using-custom-reverse-manager); I want the reverse related manager to use the plain manager by default, as I'm refactoring an existing project and would prefer not to change every reverse related manager reference.

Answer (score 1):

In [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/managers/#using-managers-for-related-object-access) section the docs say the behavior is exactly what you want it to be.

The [implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7.7/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L512) also seems to do exactly what you want. [1.6](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6.11/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L267) too.

**Update:**

If you don't want to change every usage, then create subclass of `ForeignKey`, which uses subclass of `ForeignRelatedObjectsDescriptor` as a `related_accessor_class` with [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4ee08958f154594b538207a53c1d457687b3f7ae/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L873) method overwritten.

Pseudo code:

```
class PlainManagerForeignRelatedObjectDescriptor(ForeignRelatedObjectDescriptor):

    @cached_property
    def related_manager_cls(self):
        return create_foreign_related_manager(
            models.Manager,
            self.rel,
        )

class PlainManagerForeignKey(ForeignKEy):
    related_accessor_class = PlainManagerForeignRelatedObjectDescriptor
```

Comment: Ah yes, I misread the docs, thanks for the reality check! Will investigate why I'm getting unexpected behavior.

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon. The doc you refer to is for related objects, i.e. related by a foreign key, NOT for reverse managers e.g. `foo_set` in my question. For reverse managers, the [documented behavior](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#using-custom-reverse-manager) is what I noted in my question.